# boto3 / s3 - how can you connect with uid/pwd in like you could previously ?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have some code which I want to port to boto3.

Previously it was possible to do this :

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(sys.argv[1], sys.argv2)
```

In the current documentation it's assumed that you have a config file setup with the uid/pwd in it or that you use environment variables and so there is no explicit passing of the uid/pwd when initiating a connection.

Is it now impossible to to just pass in the values as per my example or is there some way I've missed in the documentation ?

Thanks

Comment: See: [Credentials — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing AWS Python code, the SDK can automatically find your AWS credentials. If you have setup the AWS CLI, then the credentials are stored in ~/.aws/credentials.

In your code, the first two parameters are aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. This stays the same when moving from boto to boto3.

Compare the following code. The first is for boto (your example) and the second is for boto3.

BOTO Example:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3(
    aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')

for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets():
        print(bucket.name)
```

BOTO3 Example:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')

response = client.list_buckets()

for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I just made a small edit to the code because you had put a ']' where you had meant to put a ':' . Thanks again.